# Can a single TextField in flutter have variable line height?

Tags: flutter, dart, textview, flutter-layout

I'm implementing a simple rich text editor that renders text with a text editing controller that recognises basic markdown syntax, I'll link some code down below.

Everything works fine, the only problem I'm having is when a text style requires a bigger line height, for instance an `# h1` that should be rendered as a title and therefore require a bigger line height overlaps over the previous line, as you can see in the screenshot below.

I've not been able so far to make the line height in a TextView variable based on the style of the text that is being displayed, is such thing even achievable in a Flutter TextView?

Here's a snippet of my text editing controller and a screenshot detailing my problem.

[image]

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/rendering.dart';

class AddNotePage extends StatelessWidget {
  final TextEditingController _controller = MarkdownTextEditingController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Add Note'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragDown: (_) {
          FocusScopeNode currentFocus = FocusScope.of(context);

          if (!currentFocus.hasPrimaryFocus) {
            currentFocus.unfocus();
          }
        },
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: TextField(
                style: defaultTextStyle,
                controller: _controller,
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  hintText: "Insert your message",
                  border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                  ),
                ),
                scrollPadding: EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                maxLines: null,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

const Map<String, TextStyle> defaultMarkdownStyleMap = {
  r'^# .*?$': TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 50,
  ),
  r'^## .*?$': TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 40,
  ),
  r'^### .*?$': TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 30,
  ),
  r'__(.*?)\__': TextStyle(fontStyle: FontStyle.italic, fontSize: 20),
  r'~~(.*?)~~': TextStyle(decoration: TextDecoration.lineThrough, fontSize: 20),
  r'\*\*(.*?)\*\*': TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20),
};

const TextStyle defaultTextStyle = TextStyle(fontSize: 20);

class MarkdownTextEditingController extends TextEditingController {
  final Map<String, TextStyle> styleMap;
  final Pattern pattern;

  MarkdownTextEditingController({this.styleMap = defaultMarkdownStyleMap})
      : pattern = RegExp(
            styleMap.keys.map((key) {
              return key;
            }).join('|'),
            multiLine: true);

  @override
  TextSpan buildTextSpan(
      {required BuildContext context,
      TextStyle? style,
      required bool withComposing}) {
    final List<InlineSpan> children = [];

    text.splitMapJoin(
      pattern,
      onMatch: (Match match) {
        TextStyle? markdownStyle = styleMap[styleMap.keys.firstWhere(
          (e) {
            return RegExp(e).hasMatch(match[0]!);
          },
        )];

        children.add(TextSpan(
          text: match[0],
          style: style!.merge(markdownStyle),
        ));
        return "";
      },
      onNonMatch: (String text) {
        children
            .add(TextSpan(text: text, style: style!.merge(defaultTextStyle)));
        return "";
      },
    );

    return TextSpan(style: style, children: children);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution.
All I needed to do was to play around with the `strutStyle` property of the TextField.

As the documentation states:

> The strut style used for the vertical layout.
>
> StrutStyle is used to establish a predictable vertical layout. Since
> fonts may vary depending on user input and due to font fallback,
> StrutStyle.forceStrutHeight is enabled by default to lock all lines to
> the height of the base TextStyle, provided by style. This ensures the
> typed text fits within the allotted space.